# Adjust volume via dbus

Tags: gnome, dbus

I am using an application (VMWare Workstation) which hijacks the media keys on my keyboard, so I want to use another input device (Elgato Stream Deck) to send generic media commands like 'volume up' or 'pause'. I am able to use the stream deck to send shell commands like `xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume`, and this works as long as I'm in the gnome shell, but VMWare still hijacks those messages if I'm in a VM. Lower-level commands using tools like `wmctrl` or `dbus-send`, on the other hand, work fine. So, what would be the `dbus-send` equivalent to `xdotool key XF86Audio*` commands?

I can use `dbus-monitor` to view events when pressing the media keys and see, for example:

```
signal time=1599582032.226007 sender=:1.66 -> destination=:1.96 serial=18241 path=/org/gnome/Shell; interface=org.gnome.Shell; member=AcceleratorActivated
   uint32 140
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "device-id"
         variant             uint32 12
      )
      dict entry(
         string "timestamp"
         variant             uint32 504924437
      )
      dict entry(
         string "action-mode"
         variant             uint32 1
      )
      dict entry(
         string "device-node"
         variant             string "/dev/input/event7"
      )
   ]
```

for volume-up. How can I translate this into a `dbus-send` message?

I found this question from long-ago, but it appears to be obsolete. At least, it does not work on my system (Ubuntu 20.04): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830858/controlling-gnome-volume-using-dbus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pulsemixer` ended up doing what I needed. `pactl` can set the volume, but won't report a level back for the OSD to display. This script raises/lowers volume or toggles mute, and shows the appropriate OSD:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# must be set correctly for pactl to connect
uid=$(id -u)
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$uid


case "$1" in
    up )
        pulsemixer --change-volume +5 --max-volume 100
        ;;
    down )
        pulsemixer --change-volume -5
        ;;
    mute )
        pulsemixer --toggle-mute
        ;;
esac

# get active levels
sink=$(pulsemixer --list-sinks | grep -e "Default$" | cut -d',' -f2 | cut -c8-)
vol=$(pulsemixer --get-volume | cut -d' ' -f1)
mute=$(pulsemixer --get-mute)

# set osd icon
if [ $mute -eq 1 ]; then
    icon="audio-volume-muted"   
elif [ $vol -lt 33 ]; then
    icon="audio-volume-low"
elif [ $vol -lt 66 ]; then
    icon="audio-volume-medium"
else
    icon="audio-volume-high"
fi

# format as decimal
if [ $vol -eq 100 ]; then
    vol="1.0"
else 
    vol="0.$vol"
fi

gdbus call --session --dest 'org.gnome.Shell' --object-path '/org/gnome/Shell' --method 'org.gnome.Shell.ShowOSD' "{'icon': <'$icon'>, 'label': <'$sink'>, 'level': <$vol>}"
```